# how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it

Tags: wpf

I want to close a System.Windows.Window if the user clicks anywhere outside it. The Window is shown as a Dialogbox. How do I receive clicks outside a wpf window?

```
AppointmentDetailsView.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: i would not like this behavior as a user ;)

Comment: @blindmeis obviously you haven't come across a use case. check metrotwit.

Answer (score 24):

How about this?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivated(e);
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much simpler solution and it works.  You could also just add an event handler to the Deactivated event in XAML or in code:  
    'Deactivated="Window_Deactivated"'  <!-- in XAML -->
    or 'Deactivated += Window_Deactivated;' /* in code */ respectively. 
Then just call close(); in the handler.

Comment: There is one issue with this; if a user presses the X in the upper right corner, the window will be closing and the Close operation will generate an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in close operation. Exception will not generate.
Unsubscribe "Deactivate" event before calling Close method in Close button event.

```
e.g.
this.Deactivate -= OnDeactivate();
this.Close();
```