# What is the event which fires every time when i click outside for my wpf page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i am developing windows application using wpf. I want to do some functionality when i click outside of my control created. for example, if i have Message-box open in my window, i want to do some function if i click outside of my Message-box window.

I tried,

```
    private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
      .....
    }
```

but its not working.. please any one tell me, what is the event fire when i click outside of my control?

Comment: Did you try LostFocus?

Answer (score 0):

you have two supposed solutions:

one of them is to get Mouse.X, Mouse.Y from System not from application, this article will help
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

second which is better is not using Dialog, but use PopUp window and this article will help

[how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828921/how-to-close-a-wpf-dialog-window-when-the-user-clicks-outside-it)