# how to close a WPF Dialog Window when user try to touch past window screen

Tags: c#, wpf

Please look at image,

[image]

It has two windows, red one opens after green one.

How could I close red windows **when user touch green screen**?

Also I have using

```
protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDeactivated(e);
    Close();
}
```

But this works only when user open another application

here is my green window code, that opens red window

```
MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Window1 w=new Window1();
            w.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Is your red window modal or not?

Comment: If the MainWindow opened Window1 it could keep a reference. Once the MainWindow is 'touched' (whatever that means) the MainWindow could close Window1 by calling Close on that reference. Unless Window1 is modal perhaps.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I have adding code of first window

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I have adding two windows to my project, also I have editing my question , so you can see how I call it. thanks

Comment: Because Window1 is opened using ShowDialog it needs to be closed BEFORE other windows of the same application can receive events. Apparently you do not want that behavior so maybe you'd want to experiment with using Show.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a direct answer since I do not do WPF programming, but an approach I use on IOS is to have one big form, the outer part is transparent and
it actually contains one huge button, which is also transparent, only the Window1 is visible. On the button press event close window1.

But I am pretty sure you should have a way to detect click events on the green part and then close the window1. Maybe add some event listener to some component you place on the green part.

See this answer:
[how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828921/how-to-close-a-wpf-dialog-window-when-the-user-clicks-outside-it)

Here is a answer I copied:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDeactivated(e);
    Close();
}
```

}

Comment: Wow, your idea is too good, will try to provide such a thing now,  thanks :)

Comment: The red window is opened as modal window. As far as I know you won't get any click events at the green window in this case.

Comment: I have updated the answer.. seems this is a duplicate question, see my answer again.

Comment: @Wayne Thanks, but did you see my question, Your answer is on my question

Comment: Sorry my bad, all I can suggest then is to look at the "Window" hook methods, perhaps one will be called when you click outside. What about adding a MouseDown Event handler and see if it gets called if you click outside. If you get an event then you can dismiss your modal dialog from there. I'm just guessing at this.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for your suggest and sorry for delay, Microsoft isn't support it