# Show a message when user clicks outside a window thats launched as ShowDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Sample Wpf application where I am launching a Window from the Main Window that is launched in full screen. Whenever the user clicks outside of the child Window thats launched I want to show a messagebox. I actually referred to this post [how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828921/how-to-close-a-wpf-dialog-window-when-the-user-clicks-outside-it).

But the problem is the Deactivated in my case only gets raised when the child window is closed in this case. Please help how I can achieve this. 
Edit: Note I want to ShowDialog as I want the child window to be a blocking window.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window w = new Window();
            w.Height = 990;
            w.Width = 1840;
            w.MaxHeight = 990;
            w.Width = 1840;
            w.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            w.Top = this.Height - w.Height;
            w.Left = this.Width - w.Width;
            w.Deactivated += W_Deactivated;
            w.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void W_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked out");
        }
```

Comment: You probably can't successfully use [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Wpf. But [Mouse.Capture()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.capture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should work. You'll need to set the capture in multiple events. When you capture the Mouse, a click event is reported even though it's generated outside of that Window.

Comment: Oh in the child window in multiple events I should say Mouse.Capture(). Thanks I'll take a look

Comment: Ya I was actually searching about Mouse.Capture but on click of the child window I can get the Mouse X and Y coordinates. Can you please give me an example to check if the X and Y coordinates are outside the child window.

Comment: There isn't much to do. To try it out, insert this in the Activated event  of the Dialog: `bool success = Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.Element);` and subscribe its `Window_MouseDown` event. You'll need to check if the Mouse click point (`Point p = e.GetPosition(this);`) is outside of that Window bounds. Ask @Naidu to help you out in this.

Comment: Thanks Jimi I'll try it out.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Jimi. I am able to get the point when user is clicking even outside the Window. My Visual Studio crashed so I will try the rest tomorrow. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Allright. When you're at it, take also a look at [Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownOutsideCapturedElementHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.addpreviewmousedownoutsidecapturedelementhandler(v=vs.110).aspx). It will give you a hand to overcome the quirks of the WPF interface (in relation to the Mouse.Capture and its timely release).

Comment: Thanks so much Jimi I'll take a look

Comment: It works Jimi but the problem is putting MouseCapture inside OnActivated Blocks the UI on the Child Window

Comment: I had missed your comment (remember the @ prepended to the Nickname). I gave you a hint about the *Mouse.Capture and its timely release*. The `Activated` event subscription needs to be complemented with a handler that releases the capture on a `MouseDown` event and re-capture on a `MouseUp` event. Look, if you want, I'll post some code that can get you started on this.

Comment: @Jimi Sure Jimi can you please post some sample code. Thank You. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm using the using `System.Windows.Input` [InputManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Input.InputManager);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) [PreProcessInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager.preprocessinput?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to preview a Mouse input event, filtered by [e.StagingItem.Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.notifyinputeventargs.stagingitem?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Input.NotifyInputEventArgs.StagingItem);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), generated on a defined element (`Window`).

Then, calculate the position of a Mouse Left click with `element.RestoreBounds.Contains(element.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(element)))`.
If the click is generated outside the element `Bounds`, the Window shows a message, then closes (or quits the app).

The Mouse capture is activated using [UIElement.CaptureMouse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.CaptureMouse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) and released on a `MouseDown` event with [UIElement.ReleaseMouseCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.UIElement.ReleaseMouseCapture);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).
It's more or less the same as using  [Mouse.Capture()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.capture?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Input.Mouse.Capture);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Note that you can click on your Window controls, but if you drag the `Window` using its `TitleBar`, the `MouseUp` event is not rised (by default it's eaten).
If this is an issue, create a logic that detects whether the mouse event was generated in that area and restore the capture after the `MouseDown` has completed.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

public partial class YourWindow : Window
{
    MouseCapturePreview MouseCaptureHandler;
    //(...)

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseCaptureHandler = new MouseCapturePreview(this);
        //(...)
    }

    public class MouseCapturePreview
    {
        public MouseCapturePreview(Window element)
        {
            InputManager.Current.PreProcessInput += (s, e) => {
                if (e.StagingItem.Input is MouseButtonEventArgs)
                    Handler(s, (MouseButtonEventArgs)e.StagingItem.Input);
            };

            void Handler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event Received");
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mouse Released");
                    element.ReleaseMouseCapture();
                    Mouse.Capture(element);
                    if (!element.RestoreBounds.Contains(element.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(element))))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Clicked outside");
                        MessageBox.Show("You clicked outside, time to close.");
                        //Application.Current.Shutdown();
                        element.Close();
                    }
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mouse Captured");
                    element.CaptureMouse();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Activated");
        this.CaptureMouse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation @Jimi. I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way with a few steps done. You could create an eventhandler of parent inside the child view.. and don't call `ShowDialog()` just call `Dialog()`

This is the parent window, where you shouldn't click on once child window opens.

```
public partial class Parent : Window
{
    private void OpenDialog_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          Child child = new Child(this);
          child.Show();
    }
}
```

This is child window, acts as a dialog and prevents user to click on parent.

```
public partial class Child : Window
{
    private Parent _parent;

    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _parent = parent;
        parent.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(this.ParentWindow_PreviewMouseDown);       
        this.Closed += new System.EventHandler(this.Window_Closed);         
    }

    // If you click the parent, you get a message and child window will be top most again
    private void ParentWindow_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("na ah");
        this.Topmost = true;
    }

    // If you forget this, you will keep getting that "na ah" message even after closing child window.
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parent.PreviewMouseDown -= new MouseButtonEventHandler(ParentWindow_PreviewMouseDown);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
w.Show();
```

Because earlier one is modal dialog (`Showdialog()`), you can not go further until you close it.

Comment: Yea but I want my Child to be a blocking Window thats why I said ShowDialog.Is it possible to do.

Comment: No... But if you click out side your main window, then you code works in either case. As long as you are on modal window, you can not click in your main window area..

Comment: Hmm but I want to track the change in the main Window when the child window is open and it's blocking. Is there anyway I can achieve this? I want to display a message saying please close the child first.

Comment: Then go with popup window.. May be it could be modal again...Look for "The Popup loses mouse capture and the window closes when a mouse event occurs outside the Popup window. " in below link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview

Comment: Hmm ok. That makes sense. I created a sample application to replicate this. But probably I think in the actual code base being so huge I can't easily make that change. But I'll take that as a no since ShowDialog will actually block.

Comment: Hi Naidu like Jimi said can you post some sample code to check how can I determine the mouse coordinates are outside the bounds of the child window.

Comment: No worries Naidu I can take care of that since I have track of what window left and top are.