# WPF - can't close window if clicking outside boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window that I  open up with `ShowDialog()`. The window will open in te center of my previous window. To close this window  with background click I found the solution:

```
protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnDeactivated(e);
   Close();
}
```

The solution only works (look in picture the bracket on bottom) if I click outside any of my windows. But if I click on my Window(right bracket) I only get that sound and nothing happens(OnDeactivated does not proc).

Any Ideas?
[image: Example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828921/how-to-close-a-wpf-dialog-window-when-the-user-clicks-outside-it)

Comment: Your Window is probably modal

Comment: I tried with Show() but then my window just closes instantly as it opens..

Answer (score 2):

Because `ShowDialog` prevents you from activating dialog's parent window, hence no activation change is made, hence no proccing.

You could use `Show`, as in non-modal way to show your dialog form, in case you don't "wait" on the calling code for the dialog to finish with some result.

If you do, there are workarounds, like a callback solution, or a [how to close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828921/how-to-close-a-wpf-dialog-window-when-the-user-clicks-outside-it) link that @BWA pointed out.

Comment: I wanted to use `Show`, but unfortunately I need to wait for that window to close first...